# Display a branch other than master on GitHub project home page

Tags: github

The regular main page (https://github.com/username/repo) for a repo on GitHub displays the `master` branch by default.

Is there a way to make it display another branch as the default, say if I make a branch called `main`, `default`, `head` etc.?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439951/how-can-i-use-a-branch-other-than-master-for-user-github-pages | https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/212

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repository Administration - Options - Settings - Default branch select-box

Change "master" to any (existing) branch

[image]